# Не выводится обратный слэш

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать загрузку для игры в консоли, и при попытке вывода `\` пишет:

```
File "main.py", line 4
    print('\')
             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: обратный слэш - специальный символ `print('\\')`

Comment: Вам даже подсветка кода в вопросе подсказывает в чём проблема.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: он задал вполне нормальный вопрос, почему -2 голоса?

Answer (score 4):

То с чем вы столкнулись, называется экранированием специальных символов. Ибо как вам в строку записать символ одинарной кавычки? ''' - это ошибка, правильным решением будет экранировать символ одинарной кавычки поставив перед ней обратный слэш, вот так - '\''. Обратный слэш используется для экранирования спецсимволов.

Например:

```
'\'', '\n', '\r'
```

Чтобы вставить в строку символ обратного слэша, его тоже нужно экранировать:

```
'\\'
```