# Скачать файлы по списку Python

Tags: python

Уважаемые подскажите.
В текстовом файле link1.txt есть список файлов для скачивания.
Ссылок может быть много. Не более 50.

Содержимое файла link1.txt:

```
https://pastebin.com/raw/TV3nbexd
https://webhalpme.ru/if.m3u
https://iptvm3u.ru/iptvhd.m3u
```

Задача скрипта:
Построчно скачать все файлы из link1.txt ---- название.m3u --- в каталог скрипта.
C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Скачать m3u

Название скрипта: download_m3u.py

Все скаченные файлы со своим названием должны быть загружены в эту же директорию
C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Скачать m3u

Answer (score 1):

Пробежаться по файлу:

```
f = open('link1.txt')
while f:
    try:
        link = f.readline()
        print(link)  # Строка из файла
    except:
        print('Неожиданная ошибка чтения')
f.close()
```

Для загрузки файлов можно использовать библиотеку [requests](https://bdseo.ru/kak-skachat-fajl-na-python-3)

PS: так как вы, очевидно, используете OS Windows, [не наступите на грабли с экранированием в глобальных путях к файлам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106010/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C/1106021#1106021)